# Use of と見える in this sentence

Tags: grammar, nuances, particle-と

I understand that と見える can come after a noun, a verb and an i-adjective and means 'seems'. Could you please provide some simple examples of how to use this construct with a **noun**? I can't think of an example where this would be meaningful.

For i-adjectives does the following examples have different meaning/nuance おいしいと見える and おいしそうだ

Also, I can't figure out how it works in this quote:

> 私には本物の若殿様がわかります。
>
> 若様は手習いのあとと見えて、手に墨がついております。」
>
> I know who the real young lord is. ***It seems it is after*** the young lord's writing practice and his hands are stained with ink.

In this case と見える doesn't come after noun, verb or adjective and my translation sounds very clumsy. Thanks.

Comment: That あと is "trace".

Answer (score 1):

と can be used with either a sentence or a noun.

```
with 思う
彼は正しいと思う (with sentence, "[I] think he is right")
これを形見と思う (with noun, "[I] think of it as a keepsake")

with 見られる
地震が原因で倒壊したとみられる (with sentence, "[It] collapsed probably due to the earthquake")
地震が原因と見られる (with noun, "the earthquake is probably the cause")
```

～と見える means "it seems that...".
However, it is considered very formal or old.

```
先生はお忙しいと見える (with sentence, "The professor seems to be busy.")
先生は多忙と見える (with noun, same meaning)
```

Some more...
    彼はなかなかの秀才と見え、あの問題を一瞬で解いてしまった (he seems very talented, and solved that problem in an instant.)
    やつはなかなかの堅物と見える (that guy seems too serious)

Your example

```
おいしいと見える
```

is correct but very unnatural, because it combines informal/conversational (おいしい) and formal/historic (～と見える) words. (By the way, おいしいと見える is sentence+～と見える、with the sentence's subject etc. are let out).

That said, the difference between ～そうだ and ～と見える in

```
先生はお忙しそうだ
先生は多忙と見える
```

is that, as I already said, the latter is much more formal (but not 敬語. The polite version is 先生はご多忙とお見受けする)

```
若様は手習いのあとと見えて
It seems it is after the young lord's writing practice,
```

The meaning of あと is "after," but grammatically it is a noun in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Here it means simply "to see", but I think it means more appears than that and more than "seems". I think the idea is that what is seen is clear and apparent.  For example:

> 竜巻のあとと見えて、風速がEF5のしきいを超えたことをすぐに理解できる。
>
> Upon seeing the ruins/remains/trace of the tornado, it's easy to understand the wind speeds were in the realm of an [EF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Fujita_scale).

Though that's just my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

**美味しいと見える** does not work as grammar. If Japanese people say it, it means the same as **おいしそうだ**.

Comment: "does not work as grammar" Do you mean it's ungrammatical? If you mean that _and_ assume that Japanese people say it, then it can't be a very good grammar...

Comment: 「おいしいと見える」 is completely grammatical.  It does not, however,  mean "That looks yummy!" said upon seeing food.  (And I am being unable to see if OP understands this from reading his/her question.  Hence my hesitation in posting an answer.)

Comment: Ok I searched about it. I'm sorry, It is  completely grammatical. と見える means available to recognize. So おいしいと見える means 'it is available to recognize delicious' does this sentence work?

Comment: @l'électeur I don't undertand why it wouldn't mean "That looks/seems yummy!". Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell what 'it is available to recognize delicious' is intended to mean.